# Default Unicode Font Available in Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows, unicode, fonts, crystal-reports, windows-server-2003

Can anyone tell me does windows server 2003 come with unicode font that can be used in crystal report?

Comment: Windows has been a Unicode operating system for the past 19 years.  There is no such thing as a non-Unicode font.  Not every possible codepoint is supported by every font, there are too many of them.  You can check with the Charmap.exe utility.

Comment: In addition to what Hans said, most font rendering technologies support font substitution or fallback which will take glyphs from a different font if they're not available in the currently-selected one. This is most useful for different scripts (e.g. mixing CJK with Latin) and thus might come a bit unexpected if you just happen to include a Latin character that isn't available in the selected font. Generally you can expect at least Basic Latin, Greek and Cyrillic to work out of the box in nearly any included font. Script support in general is much more complete, though.

Comment: the problem i encounter is i cannot find a font can show both CHT (Chinese-Traditional) adn CHS(Chinese-Simplified)

Answer (score 2):

"Unicode font" is an imprecise term for a font with wide coverage of the Unicode character set.  Microsoft has two such fonts (that I'm aware of):  [Arial Unicode MS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial_Unicode_MS) and [Lucida Sans Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucida_Sans_Unicode).  Neither one comes with older versions of Windows.

So the answer to your question is no.

Arial Unicode MS is included in most versions of Office, so it's not uncommon to find that one on a machine with an older OS, but you cannot rely on it being there.  It also has some deficiencies with respect to kerning and certain combining marks, even compared to the regular Arial font (that doesn't have the broad script support).

Your best bet is to rely on the OS to do font linking and font fallback for you.  If that's not an option, you'll have to implement your own, but it's not easy.

Comment: Is it legal to install the Arial Unicode MS to Windows Server 2003, given i don't have office installed in the Server?

Comment: I'm not a lawyer.  There seems to be licensing information here:  http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?fmid=1081

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find a suitable font installed by default in Windows, perhaps you can use one that can be installed freely. There are many such, and guides to help you find them. One guide: http://www.unifont.org/fontguide/